# Why can MySQL have different output when printed to console / redirected to file

Tags: mysql, bash

When printed directly to console, it's like:

```
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

However, if the output is redirected to a file (mysql -e ... > file), then it's in TSV format, without any "-" or "+".

The question is, how do I implement the same trick? Is it a feature embedded in Bash?

Comment: *"Is it a feature embedded in Bash?"* -- `bash` is not involved. It works the same no matter what shell do you use to launch `mysql`. It checks if its `stdout` is a `tty` and draws the table or dumps the data as CSV depending on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [--table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-shell-output-table-format.html) option to achieve the expected format when redirecting the output:

```
mysql -e ... --table > file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :-) To bring the question a bit further, could you check the last line of question I just updated?

Comment: I'm sorry, but follow up questions must be asked separately in their own question. Your edit made all the answers invalid, therefore I roll back the edit to the original question.

Comment: I might have not described it clearly. Anyway, is there any similar option with which the output will be formatted to TSV when dumped to console? Sometimes I need to copy/paste result from console to spreadsheet and clean TSV is needed.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @axiac I disagree

Comment: I saw that. You also disagree with the OP and change their question to match your answer.

Comment: @axiac There is a difference between changing the question and rolling it back to a previous version. My answer and the other one was provided to a previous version of the question, which was different. My answer matched that question. All I did was to roll the question back.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. You understood something, I understood something else from it. It happens that the OP detailed the *"how do I implement the same trick"* part in a way that didn't match your interpretation and you reverted the question instead of updating or deleting your mismatching answer.

Comment: @axiac yousay it was ambiguous, I say it was clearly asking for sg, which I provided an answer for. Then the question was subsequently edited by the OP significantly changing its meaning. But I'm done arguing with you. You are free to provide your answer.

Comment: @IsilmëO. Use the --batch option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `tee`.
I'm not sure if this also works on MySQL, but it should, as it works for MariaDB.

In the mysql console:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> tee file.txt
Logging to file 'file.txt'
```

This does not only log results, this one also logs queries and other stuff.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| ....               |
| ....               |
```

Hope this helps

Comment: --tee works in the interactive session only. The question is about the batch mode.